# How to prevent clone my application what hosted in Apache server using Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: server, apache2, encryption

I have web application working offline it hosted in Apache server using Ubuntu 16.04.
How can i prevent any copy of my application files even with any live CD or try Ubuntu?
i tried disk encryption but i will not be there to put the the passphrase key.
What is the best solution to prevent any illegal copy?
Note: i am a beginner of using Ubuntu.

Comment: If you're not encrypting the system, you have no options that can't be circumvented with a live OS. Even if you were to encrypt the application and mount it decrypted in a temporary directory, there is nothing to stop someone from accessing the information in the decrypted directory. If the system is not encrypted, they can easily tweak it to gain root access from a live OS.

Answer (score 0):

From the [10 immutable laws of security](https://www.marshall.edu/it/departments/information-security/10-immutable-laws-of-security/):

- Law #2: If a bad guy can alter the operating system on your computer, it’s not your computer anymore
- Law #3: If a bad guy has unrestricted physical access to your computer, it’s not your computer anymore

If they're able to boot with a live CD, law #3 is the obvious choice. As you're unwilling to use file system level encryption, law #2 is true as well. In conclusion: it's not your computer anymore, and nothing you do can stop someone with physical access from copying.

Host it in a data center you trust. Use Microsoft Azure or similar; they're rather unlikely to start stealing clients data, as what they sell is essentially the idea that they're at least equally secure when compared with in-house data centers. If you're paranoid, make them sign a Non-Disclosure Agreement.